# Jersey RESTfull service with JSON

Tags: java, json, parsing, jersey

I want to parse the values from the JSON-Post into Java-Variables. But they are always empty!

JSON-Post:

```
{"algID":0,"vertices":[1,2,3]}
```

My try to parse it into Java-Variables:

```
  @POST
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Path("getCloseness_vertices")
  public String getCloseness_vertices(
  @FormParam("algID") int algID,
  @FormParam("vertices") IntArray vertices)
```

If i try it like this:

```
public String getCloseness_vertices(int algID)
```

Tomcat says:

> A message body reader for Java class int, and Java type int, and MIME
>   media type application/json; charset=UTF-8 was not found.

Any help would be nice, I just don't get it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a POJO that Jersey can serialize the JSON to:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
@XmlRootElement
public class MyPojo {
    public int algID;
    public int[] verticies;

    public MyPojo() {} // constructor is required

}
```

Then ...

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("getCloseness_vertices")
public String getCloseness_vertices(MyPojo p) 
{
    int i = p.algID;
}
```

Also you need to include the [jersey-json](https://maven.java.net/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=releases&g=com.sun.jersey&a=jersey-json&v=1.9&e=jar) jar file.