# Unsupported Media Type with Java POST request

Tags: javascript, java, post

I have a java class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class RoomInfo {
    @XmlElement
    public String name;
    @XmlElement
    public String w;
    @XmlElement
    public String h;
    @XmlElement
    public String size;
}
```

And a restful web service:

```
@Path("/create")
public class Create {
    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public void getInfo(RoomInfo room){
        System.out.println("signal");
        System.out.println(room.name);
        System.out.println(room.w);
        System.out.println(room.h);
        System.out.println(room.size);
    }
}
```

I am trying to send a POST request with json parameters with javascript:

```
var xh = new XMLHttpRequest();
var json = JSON.stringify({
    name: "Room1",
    w: "2",
    h: "4",
    size: "12"
});

xh.open("POST", 'http://localhost:8080/create', true);
xh.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
console.log(json);
xh.send(json);
```

But I get the following output in the console of my browser:

{"name":"Room1","w":"2","h":"4","size":"12"}

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

I understand that for some reason the data I send cannot be put into my RoomInfo object but I don't understand why.

The server console also shows the following:
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity A message body reader for Java class com.example.jersey.RoomInfo, and Java type class com.example.jersey.RoomInfo, and MIME media type application/json; charset=UTF-8 was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json; charset=UTF-8 ->

Comment: is there any exception on your server console?

Comment: @gurvinder372 Yes there is, I'll add it to the post

Comment: something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388288/jersey-restfull-service-with-json

Comment: @gurvinder372 But I already have a POJO, adding a constructor to it didn't have any effect, and everything else is the same as in that answer

Comment: Do you have a library setup to serialize and deserialize JSON in your Java application?  In order for my RESTful services to be able to convert from JSON I have to provide an instance of JacksonJsonProvider in the constructor of my class that extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application.  There are other libraries as well, but Jackson is the only one I really have experience with.

Answer (score 0):

For the POST to work correctly your POST needs to set a 'Content-Type' header of 'application/json'

Then your POST method may also need @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

Also the POJO does need a default constructor as mentioned above.