# 415 Unsupported Media Type / Ticket Reservation System

Tags: java, json

I write simple web-service which has 4 method: I stopped on getFilmList. When i run project i receives error in WizToolsRestClient: 415 Unsuported .., and in tomcat logs this:

```
sty 18, 2016 5:13:12 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest getEntity
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class Request.Request, and Java type class Request.Request, and MIME media type application/json; charset=UTF-8 was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json; charset=UTF-8 ->
```

My method in DAO:

```
 public List<Film> listFilms (Date date)
{
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;

    try{
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("FROM film WHERE date = :date");
        query.setDate("date" , date);
        List<Film> films = query.list();
        return films;
    }
    catch (HibernateException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Implementation in WebService:

```
@POST
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Path("/list")
public Response getFilmList (Request request)
{
    Response response = new Response();

    try {
        response.setFilms(dao.listFilms(request.getFilm().getDate()));
    }
    catch (HibernateException e)
    {

    }
    return response;
}
```

Entity class Film:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@Table (name = "film")
public class Film
{
@Id
@Column (name = "id")
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
@Column (name = "title")
private String title;
@Column (name = "date")
private Date date;

public Film() {}    //Constuctor

// geter and seter
```

Request:

```
public class Request
{
    Film film = new Film();

    public Request() {
    }

    // geter and seter
```

Response:

```
public class Response
{
  private List<Film> films;


  public Response() {
 }
```

and my json

```
{
    "Film": 
    {
        "date" : "2016-01-21"
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jersey RESTfull service with JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388288/jersey-restfull-service-with-json)

Comment: unfortunately, did not work :(

Comment: Paste full request

Comment: Umm its asked 3 years ago? Why did that pop on the top of question list?

Comment: Because @Alessio fixed a typo in the title. Please don't do that for 3y/o posts, the bump is likely to bother more people than the typo.

Comment: could you please share your request header.